# Can container and ranges algorithm be two operands of function composition operator in c++20?

Tags: c++, range, c++20, function-composition

As we know that in c++20 pipe operator `|` stands for function composition but here in below code we are passing one container and one algorithm so how is it working and how we are able to pass different container types to same function?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vnumbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::list<int> lnumbers = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    auto vresults = vnumbers | std::views::filter([](int n){ return n % 3 == 0; });
    auto lresults = lnumbers | std::views::filter([](int n){ return n % 3 == 0; });
    for (auto e:vresults)
    {
        std::cout<<"V:"<<e<<std::endl;
    }
    for (auto e:lresults)
    {
        std::cout<<"L:"<<e<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `|` is not for function composition. Function composition means taking 2 _functions_ and giving back 1 _function_ which, given an argument passes it to the first function, and then the result to the second function. [This](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga3b16146e53efcdf9ecbb9a7b21f8cd0b) is function composition.

Comment: @Enlico check example code here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges and here https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-the-ranges-library

Comment: The first link doesn't read _function composition_; the second link, I don't think it has the same authority as the first link; and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) is function composition. Function composition means _composing_ functions. When you write `vnumbers | something`, `vnumbers` is not a function, so what is `|` composing `something` with?

Comment: correct that is where my confusion is if '|' denotes function composition in c++20 then both of it's operands should be function and since vnumbers is not a function then how it is working ?

Comment: Ok, in this case I apologize for not finishing reading the function. I'll answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

> As we know that in c++20 pipe operator `|` stands for function composition but here in below code we are passing one container and one algorithm so how is it working

Saying that `|` stands for function composition is a bit inaccurate, exactly for the reason you mention in your question: function composition allows composing *functions* together, in line with the [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

On the other hand, when we don't want to be too pedantic, we can accept that *composing functions* means *"using them with a nice syntax that allows piping a single flow of data through many of them"*. That's kind of what Range-v3 and `<ranges>` allows. Writing this

```cpp
auto out = in | filter(f) | tranform(g) | take(n) | drop(m);
```

means the same as this (modulo I've not tested, probably the arguments go the other way around, I don't rememeber, as I always use the `|` syntax)

```cpp
auto out = drop(take(transform(filter(in, f), g), n), m);
```

which means that you are applying to `in` the composition of 4 functions. **BUT** those 4 functions are ***not*** `filter`, `transform`, `take`, and `drop`, but rather those 4 functions with their second argument bound to `f`, `g`, `n`, and `m` respectively.

Boost.Hana does offer a function composition function called [`boost::hana::compose`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga3b16146e53efcdf9ecbb9a7b21f8cd0b).

Notice that *functions with their second argument bound to* refers to what is known as *"partial function application"*, and Boost.Hana also gives you that, via [`boost::hana::partial`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga778b2daa27882e71d28b6f2b38982ddf) and [`boost::hana::reverse_partial`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga6e648f0d3fc0209ec024e9d759a5e8f8).

> how we are able to pass different container types to same function?

Well, we are in C++ and we have templates, so passing objects of different types to the same "function" (well, function template) shouldn't scare us. In the context of ranges, all those functions/function objects `filter`, `transform`, and so on, expect a [range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range), i.e. something on which `begin` and `end` can be called, so both `std::vector` and `std::list` comply with the requirement.